# gRPC and one way request feature

Tags: grpc

Apache Thrift provides one way request feature.

"An [oneway modifier](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/types) keyword may be added to a void function, which will generate code that does not wait for a response."

Does gRPC provide one way request like Apache Thrift?

Comment: Are you asking about "fire-and-forget" semantics? If so, [these were considered for gRPC but not included](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/2147).